# Why is $\sum_{k = 2}^{n}\frac{1}{k} \leq \int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{x}\,dx?$

Tags: calculus

Why is the below statement true algebraically? If you graph it, it becomes obvious why it's true of course.

$$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1k\leq\int_1^n\frac1x\,dx$$

Comment: Hint: draw a picture approximating the area under the curve $y=1/x$ by a Riemann sum of rectangles.

Comment: I understand why it's true geometrically. It's the algebra that isn't intuitive to me. Edited post to reflect my question.

Comment: Analytically, we have $\frac1x\ge \frac1k$ for $x\in[k-1,k]$; geometrically it is [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/67/Integral_Test.svg/1200px-Integral_Test.svg.png) (except that you shifted every pillar "one to the left")

Comment: The comment from @MaximilianJanisch adds  the only "algebra" you need to formalize this proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have, since the function is decreasing, $$\int_{k-1}^k\frac1x\,dx\geq\int_{k-1}^k\frac1k\,dx=\frac1k. $$ Now add.

Answer (score 2):

Any real number $x$ can be written as $x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}$, with $\lfloor x\rfloor\in\Bbb Z$ and $\{x\}\in[0,\,1)$. In your problem, the right-hand side minus the left-hand side is$$\int_1^n\frac{dx}{x}-\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1k=\sum_{k=2}^n\int_{k-1}^k\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac1k\right)dx=\sum_{k=2}^n\int_{k-1}^k\frac{k-x}{kx}dx=\int_1^n\frac{1-\{x\}}{x\lfloor x\rfloor}dx.$$This integral has a positive integrand.

Answer (score 1):

By [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) for $f(x)$ decreasing

$$\sum_{k=n_0}^n f(k)\le\int_{n_0-1}^n f(x)\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $k \ge 2$:

$1/k = \displaystyle{\int_{k-1}^{k}}(1/k)dx \le \int_{k-1}^{k}(1/x)dx$,

since $1/k \le 1/x $, $x \in [k-1, k]$.

Now sum:

$\displaystyle{\sum_{k=2}^{n}}(1/k) \le \int_{1}^{n}(1/x)dx.$

Answer (score 1):

By induction:

1. $n=2$. $$\sum_{k=2}^2\frac1k=\frac{1}{2}\le\int_{1}^{2}\frac1x dx=\ln 2\approx 0.69$$
2. $n \to n+1$. Assume that the statement holds for $n\in \mathbb N$ $$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1k\leq\int_1^n\frac1x\,dx$$ 
   then

\begin{align}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac1k&=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac1k+\frac{1}{n+1}\\&\leq\int_1^n\frac1x\,dx+\frac{1}{n+1}\\&\le \int_1^n\frac1x\,dx+\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac1{x}\,dx\\&=\int_{1}^{n+1}\frac1{x}\,dx\end{align}
$~~~~~~~\text{because our function is decreasing so we have that}$
$$\frac1{n+1}=\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac1{n+1}\,dx\le \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac1{x+1}\,dx\le \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac1{x}\,dx $$